# How do I use the result of a grouping count as a top level dimension?

Tags: tableau-api

Total Tableau newbie here. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
item1  
item1  
item2  
item1  
item5  
item2  
item5  
item6
```

I would like to use the number of times that items appear in this list as a dimension, and count how many of the identifiers in the list occurred that many times. As in:

```
Items with 1 Occurrrence: 1
Items with 2 Occurrences: 2
Items with 3 Occurrences: 1
```

In SQL I would do it this way:

```
SELECT IDAppearsTimes, COUNT(*) AS IDCount
FROM (SELECT Identifier, COUNT(*) AS IDAppearsTimes
      FROM DataSetTable
   GROUP BY Identifier) AS Data
GROUP BY IDAppearsTimes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag the same var to "Text" mark card, and turn it to Measure-Count

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Tableau does not support operations that involve creating a temporary table, such as your Data table. Not in an automatic way.

So, you have 3 options

1) Do the query, create the table and import it in Tableau

```
SELECT Identifier, COUNT(*) AS IDAppearsTimes
      FROM DataSetTable
   GROUP BY Identifier) AS Data
```

2) If your query is slow in SQL (if you have a large table, for instance), Tableau may be faster. And you should:

- Drag items and COUNTD([Number of Records]) to a sheet. This will create basically your Data table
- Export it (to mdb or csv)
- Connect to this new table, extract (extracts are always faster and more compressed)
- Profit

3) Take the query in the first option and use it to create a view in your underlying database. Then connect Tableau to that view.

Regards